How to set the filter values for a list web part in JavaScript
I created a modern experience site page in SharePoint 2019 on-premises site, and built a tree view web part on the site page.
I want to set the filter for another five list web parts on the same site page by clicking on items in the tree view. How should I implement this?
Thanks in advance.
